# How to pass html element from Laravel controller to view

Tags: html, laravel

I want to pass an HTML element from the controller to view in Laravel

For example:

```
$list = '<p>card</card>';

return view('home', ['list' => $list]);
```

Comment: This breaks MVC.

Comment: @nice_dev But is sometimes the DRYest way to accomplish something, in which case it should be preferred over seeing MVC as dogma. There's a reason Laravel allows for the possibility.

Comment: @HashimAziz The $list in the question is just a literal string according to Laravel

Answer (score 11):

The way you pass from the controller is correct. You can render HTML in your view as,

```
{!! $list !!}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data

Fiddle: https://implode.io/XnjDKO

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are going to need to pass more HTML, if you do you can try this way

View:

```
<p>card</card>
<p>card</card>
<p>card</card>
More HTML
```

Controller:

```
$view = view('your.view')->render();
```

Comment: `->render()` helped me to generate pdf report by tcpdf in controller. Thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

When you pass data in your controller to the view which is render. When you want to show that data un your view template. You have two possibility the first one is escaping everything by passing it to the `htmlspecialchars` méthode which remove any **HTML tags**. And the second method show data whitout escaping it.

1. This one will escape HTML tags
   `{{ data_provide_in_the_controller }}`
2. This will output any HTML tags contain in the variable provide

   `{!! data_provide_in_the_controller!!}`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way

```
      $data = “hello world” ;
      $ value = 15;

       Return view(‘hello’, compact(‘data’,’value’);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
$myVariable = '<b>These are bold texts</b>';

return view('home', ['myVariable' => $myVariable ]);
```

**Blade:**

`{{ $myVariable }}` output is: `<b>These are bold texts</b>`

`{!! $myVariable !!}` output is: **These are bold texts**

Also, if the variable on your controller is the same as the variable name you want to pass on the blade, you can use `compact` like so:

`return view('home', compact('myVariable'));`